# How to update sequence property of an object if it's order is changing inside another object?

Tags: javascript, object

So I have an object of objects where each inside object has it is own `seq` property which points at it's order inside the big object.

Example:

```
const obj = {
  '1': {
    name: 'apple',
    seq: 1,
    id: 1,
  },
  '2': {
    name: 'orange',
    seq: 2,
    id: 2,
  },
  '3': {
    name: 'banana',
    seq: 3,
    id: 3,
  },
}
```

My goal is to move these objects around and update their `seq` accordingly.

For example

```
const obj = {
  '1': {
    name: 'apple',
    seq: 1,
    id: 1,
  },
  '3': {
    name: 'banana',
    seq: 2,
    id: 3,
  },
  '2': {
    name: 'orange',
    seq: 3,
    id: 2,
  },
}
```

I know the id of the object I'm moving and to which position it is moving

What I have so far

```
const moveObjects = (objId, indexToMoveTo) => {
  const objCopy = Object.values(obj).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    // if element if the one we moved - set seq to index
    if (curr.id === objId) {
      prev[curr.id] = {
        ...curr,
        seq: indexToMoveTo
      };
    } else if (curr.id !== objId) {
      // if element is not the one and index is smaller - increase seq by one
      if (curr.seq >= indexToMoveTo) {
        prev[curr.id] = {
          ...curr,
          seq: curr.seq + 1
        };
      }
      // if index bigger than seq - return the element without modifying it
      else if (curr.seq < indexToMoveTo) {
        prev[curr.id] = {
          ...curr
        };
      }
    }
    return prev;
  }, {})
  return objCopy
}
```

The problem with this is that of course if you move an element around a few times seq starts to increase beyond the length of the object, it can become 4, 5, 6 for example.

Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/euwrtxgL/) to the jsfiddle to see more clearly what I mean. (the third console.log)

All the help to resolve this will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not just use an array, then you don't need to use `Object.values` and also you have access to the index whenever you want, no need to store the `seq` inside of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

For the objects to actually change position you have to change the key since the keys in an object are sorted by default.

Here is a different approach

```js
const obj = { '1': { name: 'apple', seq: 1, id: 1, }, '2': { name: 'orange', seq: 2, id: 2, }, '3': { name: 'banana', seq: 3, id: 3, }, }
const moveObjects = (objId, indexToMoveTo) => {
 arr= Object.entries(obj)
 tobj=arr.filter(o => o[1].id == objId).flat()
 tobj[1].seq = indexToMoveTo ,temp = tobj[0]
 tobj[0] = indexToMoveTo
 k = arr.splice(temp - 1, 1)
 arr.splice(indexToMoveTo-1, 0, k[0]);
arr.forEach((o,i)=>{o[1].seq = i+1, o[0] = i+1})
map=new Map([...arr])
 return Object.fromEntries(map)
}
console.log(moveObjects(3, 2))
console.log(moveObjects(1, 3))
```

if you want to keep the keys the same but only change the `seq` you could use the same code without modifying the `keys` however the objects will remain in the same place

```js
const obj = { '1': { name: 'apple', seq: 1, id: 1, }, '2': { name: 'orange', seq: 2, id: 2, }, '3': { name: 'banana', seq: 3, id: 3, }, }

 arr= Object.entries(obj)
const moveObjects = (objId, indexToMoveTo) => {
 arr= Object.entries(obj)
 tobj=arr.filter(o=>o[1].id==objId).flat()
 tobj[1].seq=indexToMoveTo ,temp=tobj[0]
 tobj[0]=indexToMoveTo
 k=arr.splice(temp-1,1)
 arr.splice(indexToMoveTo-1, 0, k[0]);
arr.forEach((o,i)=>{o[1].seq=i+1})
map=new Map([...arr])
 return Object.fromEntries(map)
}
console.log(moveObjects(3, 2))
```